# Get the touch direction on Android

Tags: android, touch, listener

I want to ask that is that possible do in android catch the in the touch mode catch the scrolling direction ? When user touch on the screen left to right, can I catch the change ?
If it is possible which listener can ı use ?

I found some of the methods and listeners but I 'm not sure that therse are represent my requirement .
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/Touch.html

Public Methods
static int  getInitialScrollX(TextView widget, Spannable buffer)
static int  getInitialScrollY(TextView widget, Spannable buffer)

If these methods enough, ıs there any example that including these methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use gestures and gesture listeners( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener.html ). The MotionEvent that you obtain in listener contains all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to detect a sideways motion, much like the used for unlocking the screen. To do that, you have to listen for a touch down event, then an up event and compare the coordinates of the two events.